# Passar Valor do ComboBox para Parametro

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo uma solução em *C# Windows forms* e estou com duvidas de como pegar uma das opções da minha combo box que é ativada quando uma *checked* é clicada. Essa Combo possui a opção de sim e não, mas quando passo ela para o parâmetro o valor vem em branco.

```
if (chbSim.Checked)
{
    txtValor.Enabled = false;
    cmBSimNao.Enabled = true;
    param.Valor = cmBSimNao.Text;
    param.Nome = this.txtNome.Text;
    param.Descricao = this.txtDescricao.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve usar o substituir o trecho abaixo:

```
    param.Valor = cmBSimNao.Text;
```

Por

```
   param.Valor = cmBSimNao.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

**A propriedade SelectedItem obtém ou define o item selecionado.**

Veja referência:
[Propriedade ComboBox.SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Tentei fazer isso, porém o parametro Valor é string, como posso convertar?

Comment: cmBSimNao.SelectedItem.ToString()

Comment: Isso mesmo que o @BrunoH. comentou. Editei a resposta.

Comment: Fiz isso e deu certo. Vlw gente!